# Find out the interval.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a,b,c, d$ be real numbers such that $a+b+c+d=0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$. Then the smallest possible value of expression $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-d)^2+(d-a)^2$ lies in the interval:

i)$(0-1.5)$

ii)$(1.5-2.5)$

iii)$(2.5-3)$

iv)$(3.5-4)$

Comment: This is hard to read. Try to read the tutorial on formatting for this site.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
I &= (a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-d)^2+(d-a)^2 \\
  &= 2(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)-2(ab+bc+cd+da) \\
  &= 2-2(a+c)(b+d) \\
  &= 2+2(a+c)^2 \ge 2
\end{align}

we can get equality at $a=b=1/2,c=d=-1/2$

Comment: we can also find the maximum: $I=2+(a+c)^2+(b+d)^2=3+2(ac+bd)\le3+a^2+c^2+b^2+d^2=4$

Comment: How 2-2(a+c)^2>=2 came? Please explain.

Comment: @user585143 it's $2+2(a+c)^2 \ge 2$, the plus sign comes from $b+d=-(a+c)$.

Comment: Thank you now it is easily understandable